# wpa_supplicant conflicting with hostapd on the same interface

Tags: networking, wpa-supplicant, wireless-access-point, hostapd

I am trying to make wpa_supplicant and hostapd work simultaneously in order to use a single interface to connect to a wifi network and to generate an access point (that does not provide internet). If I run `wpa_supplicant` first and `hostapd` next, everything works fine:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c wpa.conf -B # wpa.conf has been generated using wpa_passphrase
udhcpc -i wlan0
/bin/bash /usr/sbin/create_access_point.sh
```

However, if I run hostapd first and wpa_supplicant next, every client that was connected to the AP gets disconnected and cannot connect anymore. Specifically, if a new client tries to connect after wpa_supplicant has been launched, the client is stuck on "getting ip address..." and hostapd keeps alternating  AP-STA-CONNECTED and AP-STA-DICCONNECTED.

Output of ip route in both cases:

> ```
> default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 metric 10
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.74
> 192.168.3.0/24 dev wlan1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.3.1
> ```

content of create_access_point.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
modprobe brcmfmac
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.3.1 up
udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
hostapd /etc/myhostapd.conf
```

hostapd configuration:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=0
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=3
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0

ssid=myssid
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mypasswd
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

output of iw list:

> ```
>     Wiphy phy0
>     max # scan SSIDs: 10
>     max scan IEs length: 2048 bytes
>     max # sched scan SSIDs: 16
>     max # match sets: 16
>     max # scan plans: 1
>     max scan plan interval: 508
>     max scan plan iterations: 0
>     Retry short limit: 7
>     Retry long limit: 4
>     Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
>     Device supports roaming.
>     Supported Ciphers:
>             * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
>             * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
>             * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
>             * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
>     Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
>     Supported interface modes:
>              * IBSS
>              * managed
>              * AP
>              * P2P-client
>              * P2P-GO
>              * P2P-device
>     Band 1:
>             Capabilities: 0x1020
>                     HT20
>                     Static SM Power Save
>                     RX HT20 SGI
>                     No RX STBC
>                     Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
>                     DSSS/CCK HT40
>             Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
>             Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
>             HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
>             Bitrates (non-HT):
>                     * 1.0 Mbps
>                     * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
>                     * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
>                     * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
>                     * 6.0 Mbps
>                     * 9.0 Mbps
>                     * 12.0 Mbps
>                     * 18.0 Mbps
>                     * 24.0 Mbps
>                     * 36.0 Mbps
>                     * 48.0 Mbps
>                     * 54.0 Mbps
>             Frequencies:
>                     * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
>                     * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
>     Supported commands:
>              * new_interface
>              * set_interface
>              * new_key
>              * start_ap
>              * set_bss
>              * join_ibss
>              * set_pmksa
>              * del_pmksa
>              * flush_pmksa
>              * remain_on_channel
>              * frame
>              * set_wiphy_netns
>              * set_channel
>              * start_sched_scan
>              * start_p2p_device
>              * connect
>              * disconnect
>              * crit_protocol_start
>              * crit_protocol_stop
>              * update_connect_params
>     Supported TX frame types:
>              * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
>              * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
>              * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
>              * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
>              * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
>     Supported RX frame types:
>              * managed: 0x40 0xd0
>              * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
>              * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
>              * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
>              * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
>     software interface modes (can always be added):
>     valid interface combinations:
>              * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
>                total <= 3, #channels <= 2
>              * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
>                total <= 4, #channels <= 1
>     Device supports scan flush.
>     Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
>     Supported extended features:
>             * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_PSK ]: 4-way handshake with PSK in station mode
>             * [ 4WAY_HANDSHAKE_STA_1X ]: 4-way handshake with 802.1X in station mode
> ```

I want to be able to run hostapd at startup and wpa_supplicant later. How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to generate the access point using wpa_supplicant instead of hostapd, using this configuration:

```
network={
    ssid="TESTAP"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="password"
    frequency=2437
}
```

Now I can connect to the access point even when the device is connected to another wifi, but the client and the AP cannot ping each other.

**UPDATE 2**: adding `p2p_disabled=1` to wpa.conf allows the client of the AP (generated with hostapd) to stay connected but also in this case it is not possible to ping the AP. Killing wpa_supplicant allows to ping the AP.